# Mlxtend: SequentialFeatureSelector with ColumnTransformer gives AttributeError

Tags: python

I'm trying to use mlxtend `SequentialFeatureSelector()` in combination with a pipeline by using `ColumnTransformer()`. I use the ColumnTransformer() to make power transformations (via `PowerTransformer()`) only on the numeric variables, but not on the binary variables. My problem is that I either get the error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'` or the results make no sense.

If I define like this: `numeric_features = ['feature_1','feature_2', 'feature_3', 'feature_4', 'feature_5']`, then I get the `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'`

```
from sklearn.compose import  ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression



# RepeatedStratifiedKFold

rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=10,random_state=123)

cv_define = rskf.split(X, y)

cv = list(cv_define)


# Define pipeline (transformation & model)

numeric_features = ['feature_1','feature_2', 'feature_3', 'feature_4', 'feature_5']

# numeric_features = [0,1,2,3,4,]


numeric_transformer = make_pipeline(PowerTransformer(method = 'yeo-johnson', standardize=False))

preprocessor = make_pipeline(ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features)], remainder = 'drop'))

pipe = make_pipeline((preprocessor), (LogisticRegression(max_iter = 10000, penalty = 'none')))



# Run SFS (Sequential Feature Selector)
sfs1 = SFS(pipe, k_features = 1, scoring = "neg_log_loss", forward = False, floating = False, cv = cv, verbose = 2, n_jobs = -1)
sfs_result = sfs1.fit(X, y)
```

If I define `numeric_features` like this: `numeric_features = [0,1,2,3,4]` , then I get incorrect results (same value for every iteration) which also include NaNs. See pictures below.

[Results of the SequentialFeatureSelector() - Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oya3F.png)
[Results of the SequentialFeatureSelector() - Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJJlO.png)

The problem lies only in `preprocessor = make_pipeline(ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features)], remainder = 'drop'))`. If for example, I would remove the specific column transformation and would perform the power transformations on the whole dataset, then code works and results would be:

```
from sklearn.compose import  ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression



# RepeatedStratifiedKFold

rskf = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=10,random_state=123)

cv_define = rskf.split(X, y)

cv = list(cv_define)


# Define pipeline (transformation & model)

numeric_features ['feature_1','feature_2', 'feature_3', 'feature_4', 'feature_5']



numeric_transformer = make_pipeline(PowerTransformer(method = 'yeo-johnson', standardize=False))



pipe = make_pipeline((numeric_transformer), (LogisticRegression(max_iter = 10000, penalty = 'none')))



# Run SFS (Sequential Feature Selector)
sfs1 = SFS(pipe, k_features = 1, scoring = "neg_log_loss", forward = False, floating = False, cv = cv, verbose = 2, n_jobs = -1)
sfs_result = sfs1.fit(X, y)
```

Results:

[Working results of SFS - Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMvoU.png)
[Working result of SFS - Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S0ka.png)

Does anyone has an idea how this could be solved? Any help would be much appreciated.